# AVPlayer returns nan videos

Tags: ios, avplayer, swift4

I am trying to play videos on avplayer uing the following code...but get nothing as result as it shows duration nan.

```
func setUpPlayer(fileURL:URL){
        let playerItem:AVPlayerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: fileURL)
        player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
        let playerLayer=AVPlayerLayer(player: player!)
        playerLayer.frame=CGRect(x:self.videoContainer.frame.origin.x, y:self.videoContainer.frame.origin.y+20, width:self.videoContainer.frame.size.width, height:self.videoContainer.frame.size.height-40)
        player?.addObserver(
            self, forKeyPath:"currentItem", options:.initial, context:nil)

        self.view.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)


        rangeSlider.setVideoURL(videoURL:fileURL)
        rangeSlider.delegate = self

        self.endTime = CMTimeGetSeconds((player?.currentItem?.duration)!)


       let timeInterval: CMTime = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(0.01, 100)

//        let asset:AVURLAsset = AVURLAsset.init(url:videoURL)
//        let videoDuration:CMTime = asset.duration;
//
//
//        let timeInterval: CMTime = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(videoDuration,100)
            //CMTimeGetSeconds(videoDuration)

        timeObserver = player?.addPeriodicTimeObserver(forInterval: timeInterval,
                                                        queue: DispatchQueue.main) { (elapsedTime: CMTime) -> Void in

                                                            self.observeTime(elapsedTime: elapsedTime)

            } as AnyObject!

    }
```

I am doing this first time.Kindly give some solution to resolve this problem.Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

you missed to write "player.play()" in your code

```
let timeRange = self.avPlayer.currentItem.loadedTimeRanges[0].CMTimeRangeValue
let duration = CMTimeGetSeconds(timeRange.duration)
```

try this it will definiyely helpful

Comment: This is not at all useful.The video duration is nan or infinite ,I need help there .How can I work on that to fix that nan duration and get video in my avplayer?

Comment: Thanks,Sir. where should I add it in code.Since,I am doing it first time I am not able to manage the code properly with it.